# Passing integer value to system evoking command

Tags: c++

Could somebody let me know how to pass integer values to the command statement.

```
int lf,ff;
string cmd,filename;
cmd = "catdcd -o -otype frame.xyz -first "+lf+" -last "+ff+" "+filename+"";
system((cmd).c_str());
```

> Error: mismatched types ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>’ and ‘int’

I just tried using ...

```
cmd = "catdcd -o -otype frame.xyz -first "lf" -last "ff" "+filename+"";
```

but ended up with another error.

> error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)’

Please help. I have to increment the value of `lf` and `ff` using loop for my program.

Answer (score 0):

I fairly new to C++, so I don't know what the best way to do this is, but this should work.

```
#include<sstream>

stringstream ss;
ss << "catdcd -o -otype frame.xyz -first " << lf << " -last " << ff << " " << filename;
string cmd = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++ 11 you can use `to_string()` functions, so something like

```
int lf, ff;
string cmd, filename;
cmd = "catdcd -o -otype frame.xyz -first " + to_string(lf) + " -last " + to_string(ff) + " " + filename + "";
system((cmd).c_str());
```

should do the work.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Both the codes worked for me and I am able to run the program without any errors.. :)